# Facebook - Get unpublished and hidden posts with Real-Time API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to subscribe to the `promotable_posts` endpoint of the Facebook page to get updates for unpublished and hidden posts ("dark posts"). According to Facebook it should be possible to subscribe to that endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime#data

But that endpoint is not listed on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[APP_ID]/webhooks/ and I can't add the subscription of the endpoint via the API either. It's working for endpoints like `feed`.

How can I subscribe to that endpoint? And how can I get hidden posts? Normally I would use `https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/promotable_posts?include_hidden=true&access_token=...` to get those posts when I'm polling, but I can't tell Facebook to include hidden posts when I subscribe to an endpoint.

Comment: `but I can't tell Facebook to include hidden posts when I subscribe to an endpoint.` Seriously!

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook documentation is wrong: You don't have to subscripe to "promotable" posts to get unpublished posts and you don't have to do anything else to get "hidden" posts.

Answer (score 0):

> `is_hidden`
>   If this post is marked as hidden (Applies to Pages only)

From Facebook documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post).

This flag tells you if the posts are hidden also known as unpublished or "dark posts". Basically it's a post that is shown in public feed but not in the page feed.
However, when you make a call to FB Graph API you still get all the posts, just add this flag in your request in order to filter them later.

The best approach would be pull the data from the api, and manage it in your side, since there is no way to filter them on your calls.